# Concrete5 logging me out when I refresh in Inspect Element mode in Chrome

Tags: concrete5

Whenever I am in Inspect Element mode in Google Chrome, and logged into the CMS as either the Administrator or Standard user, and I then refresh the page, the CMS logs me out and returns the message "This user is inactive. Please contact us regarding this account.".

Is this some sort of error with the CMS? Or a security feature maybe?

I know that its not any sort of IP issue, which is why this is so strange.

It is an absolute nightmare when developing.

If anyone could shed light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

> Information
>
> Google Chrome Version: 52.0.2743.116 m
>
> Concrete5 Version Installed - 5.7.5.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the device testing mode in Chrome spoofs the UA string and concrete5 is configured by default to terminate the session when it changes.

The easiest way to change this is to overwrite the setting in a package controller as seen here: https://github.com/jakob-fuchs/concrete5-Development-Settings/blob/master/controller.php#L72

Comment: You've just eliminated a major annoyance! Thank you so much Jakob.

Comment: You can also use the shell command "concrete/bin/concrete5 c5:config set concrete.security.session.invalidate_on_user_agent_mismatch false" that can be run just once instead of at every page call (or simply use the Handyman add-on, that allows you configuring this and tons of other options)